# How to choose subsets of factor groups to complete a statistical test in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset containing several variables and I wish to statistically test the variances (Kruskal-test) for each variable seperately.

My data (df) looks like that: (carbon and nitrogen content for diffrent agricultural managements (see name)).
I have 16 groups (to simplify it, I´d say, I have got 8 groups):

extract of the data

```
1. List item
name    N_cont  C_cont  agriculture
C_ero   1,064   8,380   1
C_ero   0,961   8,086   1
C_ero   0,977   8,331   1
Ds_ero  1,767   17,443  2
Ds_ero  1,802   18,264  2
Ds_ero  2,083   20,112  2
Ms_ero  1,547   14,380  3
Ms_ero  1,566   15,313  3
Ms_ero  1,505   14,760  3
Md_ero  1,512   14,303  4
Md_ero  1,656   15,331  4
Md_ero  1,500   13,788  4
C_upsl  1,121   10,581  5
C_upsl  1,159   10,460  5
C_upsl  1,223   10,171  5
Ds_upsl 1,962   20,656  6
Ds_upsl 1,784   16,780  6
Ds_upsl 1,720   17,482  6
Ms_upsl 1,578   16,228  7
Ms_upsl 1,634   15,331  7
Ms_upsl 1,394   13,419  7
Md_upsl 1,286   11,824  8
Md_upsl 1,241   11,452  8
Md_upsl 1,317   11,932  8
```

I already put a factor for the agriculture

```
df$agriculture<-factor(df$agriculture)
```

I can do statistical tests compairing all of the 16 groups.
e.g. `kruskal.test(df$C,df$agriculture)`

But now I would like to do statistic tests just for specific groups out of the 8 groups, e.g. those which contain e.g. an `C` (Conventional) or rather `DS` (Direct seeding) in the `name` column
or e.g. `ero` (eroding site) or `upsl` (upper slope)

It did try `grep` or `split`, but it did not work, because the dimension of x and y should be the same.

Do you have any clue?

Comment: Hello. Please have a look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to subset with `grepl`. Assuming you want rows whose name contains either `DS`, `upsl` or `C` then

```
df[grepl("(DS)|(upsl)|(C)", df$name), ]

#     name  N_cont C_cont   agriculture
#1    C_ero  1,064  8,380           1
#2    C_ero  0,961  8,086           1
#3    C_ero  0,977  8,331           1
#13  C_upsl  1,121 10,581           5
#14  C_upsl  1,159 10,460           5
#15  C_upsl  1,223 10,171           5
#16 Ds_upsl  1,962 20,656           6
#17 Ds_upsl  1,784 16,780           6
#18 Ds_upsl  1,720 17,482           6
#19 Ms_upsl  1,578 16,228           7
#20 Ms_upsl  1,634 15,331           7
#21 Ms_upsl  1,394 13,419           7
#22 Md_upsl  1,286 11,824           8
#23 Md_upsl  1,241 11,452           8
#24 Md_upsl  1,317 11,932           8
```

If you do not want to hard code the `name` values , you can also try,

```
x <- c("C", "DS", "upsl")
df[grepl(paste0(x, collapse = "|"), df$name), ]
```

which would also yield the same result.

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what I´m looking for! Another little question:
Is there a possibility to get the results separately in one step, that I get a result like that (as a list):

[1]”C”
name  N_cont  C_cont   agriculture
C_ero  1,064   8,380           1
C_ero  0,961   8,086           1
C_ero  0,977   8,331           1
C_upsl  1,121   10,581   5
C_upsl  1,159   10,460   5
C_upsl  1,223   10,171   5

[2]“DS“

Ds_ero  1,767   17,443   2
Ds_ero  1,802   18,264   2
Ds_ero  2,083   20,112   2
Ds_upsl 1,962   20,656   6
Ds_upsl 1,784   16,780   6
Ds_upsl 1,720   17,482   6

Comment: not sure, what you want exactly. Could you update the question?

Answer (score 0):

Load the `data.table` package.

`library(data.table)`

Create a subset of the group you want to do your stats on: 
if your dataframe is df, then

```
DT<-data.table(df)
DT[like(name,"C_")]
```

.. OR use the `sqldf` package:

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("select * from df where name like 'C_'")
```